# Bash while loop behave differently in file vs direct execution

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

The following is the sample while loop.

```
res=()
lines=$'first\nsecond\nthird'
while read line; do
res+=("$line")
done <<< "$lines"
echo $res
```

When i run this directly in terminal im getting the following out put.

```
first second third
```

But when run the same script by saving it to a file. Then im getting the following out put.

```
first
```

Why is it behaving differently?

Note: I tested with and without shebang in file. result is same.

Comment: Use `echo "${res[@]}"` to print all array elements

Comment: Look at the output of `declare -p lines`; in the case where you see all three entries, it's actually a single element containing linebreaks (which are removed by the unquoted parameter expansion).

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2128) and other common problems

Comment: I'm guessing when you run it "directly" your shell is not bash but zsh. Only printing `first` is correct/expected/normal behavior when you have `res=( first second third )` and then run `echo $res`; you would need to use `"${res[@]}"` to expand all three elements.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, i forgot the fact that it is zsh. Thanks!!!.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with embedded newlines and want to turn it into an array split on them, use the `mapfile` builtin:

```
$ mapfile -t res <<<$'first\nsecond\nthird'
$ printf "%s\n" "${res[@]}"
first
second
third
```